# How to creat a matrix like the following shape

Tags: arrays, matlab

If `p = [p1 p2 p3 ... pn]^T` which is n-by-1.
How to create the following shape?

```
P = [p1 0;0 p1;p2 0;0 p2;p3 0;0 p3;...;pn 0;0 pn]
```

which is `2n` by `2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very straightforward way would be:

```
q = zeros(2 * size(p))
q(1:2:end, 1) = p
q(2:2:end, 2) = p
```

More concisely, you can use `kron`:

```
q = kron(p, eye(2))
```

Answer (score 2):

Let `p`  be defined, for example, as

```
p = [10 20 30 40];
```

Some possibilities:

1. Using [`sparse`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html):

   ```
   P = full(sparse([1:2:2*numel(p) 2:2:2*numel(p)], repelem([1 2], numel(p)), [p p]));
   ```
2. Using just assignment indexing:

   ```
   P = zeros(2*numel(p), 2);
   P((1:2:2*numel(p)).' + [0 2*numel(p)+1]) = [p p];
   ```
3. Using [`conv2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html):

   ```
   t = zeros(2*numel(p)-1, 1);
   t(1:2:end) = p;
   P = conv2(t, eye(2))
   ```